# In xml how to check if the element value is required during parsing

Tags: c#, xml

I have a dtd file. In this file some of the Attributes are required for an element eg:

```
<!ELEMENT NAME (LASTNAME)>
<!ATTLIST NAME SEX CDATA #REQUIRED >
```

Now while parsing the file if the attribute is now present then an error is thrown and the parsing ends; which is fine.

But what if the NAME element is like this:

```
<NAME SEX="">
 <LASTNAME>Doe</LASTNAME>
</NAME>
```

Where the attribute is there but there is no value.

How do I check for this while parsing the xml against the dtd.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XmlReader.HasValue` [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.hasvalue.aspx).

or `XmlValidatingReader.HasValue` [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlvalidatingreader.hasvalue%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

**Update:**

```
var elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName(...);
for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
{
     var attrVal = elemList[i].Attributes["Name"].Value;
     if (null == attrVal)
     {
         // no value
     } 
}
```

Comment: XmlValidatingReader has become obsolete, so cannot use this in this project.

Answer (score 0):

This is beyond the function of DTD to provide checks for empty Values.

Two things that you can do:
1. Add default value like "NoData"
2. Add minLength in your XML: `minLength="2"`

But as monocadad suggested, you can check for value by using HasValue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have the liberty to change the xml or the dtd files. I am converting a vb6 application. In the vb6 application; the value is checked for "" while parsing against the dtd. I am amazed and dumbfounded that why we wouldn't have any thing like this in framework 2.0 or higher.